# clojure gen-class varargs constructor

Tags: clojure, java-interop, clojure-java-interop, gen-class

in the :constructors map and subsequent -init definitions, how do I represent a varargs constructor (assuming the superclass has multiple constructors of which one is varargs) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since varargs are essentially syntax sugar for Object arrays, you could just use "[Ljava.lang.Object;" as the type of constructor's parameter.

Here's some sample code:

```
(ns t.vtest
  (:gen-class
   :implements   [clojure.lang.IDeref]
   :init init
   :state state
   :constructors {["[Ljava.lang.Object;"] []}))
   ;;                                      ^-----------------------
   ;; You should put "[Ljava.lang.Object;" for superclass varargs constructor here
   ;; I left it blank for the sake of working example 

(defn -init
  [args]
  (println "first element of args" (aget args 0) "total elements" (alength args))
  [[] (into [] args)])

(defn -deref
  [this]
  (.state this))
```

and that's how it looks in REPL

```
user=> @(t.vtest. (into-array Object ["A" "B" 1 2]))
first element of args A total elements 4
["A" "B" 1 2]
```

Comment: It doesn't solve problem stated in question. Rather than defining a vararg method it generates method accepting array. This is not the same. The difference is that the vararg is flagged by special ACC_VARARGS opscode in generated byte-code which clojure don't support at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Since clojure don't support it at the moment you need to patch it with: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/HMpMavh0WxA.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/HMpMavh0WxA)

And use it with new meta tag:

```
(ns t.vtest 
  (:gen-class 
   :implements   [clojure.lang.IDeref]
   :init init
   :state state
   :constructors {^:varargs ["[Ljava.lang.Object;"] []} 
  ))
```